# How can I create DIV box with a WHILE and/or FOREACH loop at X,Y coordinate with PHP?

Tags: php, html, css, mysqli

here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

- position each div/box to their appropriate X,Y coordinate in another DIV **HELP HERE PLZ**

I want position each DIV/box to their appropriate coordinates in the "map_size" DIV. All of my boxes are just being placed under each other in a straight line. thanks in advance. I want to use only HTML, PHP and CSS.

**What I have :** https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFSha.jpg

**What I want**(not all four areas of the map, just one) : http://www.chem.utoronto.ca/coursenotes/analsci/stats/images/2D_Centroid.gif

**my php top of the html file:**

```
<?php
include 'db_conn.php';

//query to get X,Y coordinates from DB
$coord_sql = "SELECT x_coord, y_coord FROM coordinates";
$coord_result = mysqli_query($conn,$coord_sql);

//see if query is good
if($coord_result === false) {
    die(mysqli_error()); 
}
?>
```

**other php part with the only DIV:**

```
<div id="map_size" align="center">
<?php

//get number of rows for X,Y coords in the table
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($coord_result)){    
//naming X,Y values
$x_pos = $row['x_coord'];
$y_pos = $row['y_coord'];


//draw a box with a DIV at its X,Y coord     
echo "<div id='desk_box' style='style:absolute;
                                    left: " . $x_pos. " px;
                                    top:  " . $y_pos. " px;'>box number</div>";
    } //end while coord_result loop

?>

    </div> <!-- end div map_Size -->
```

**my css file:**

```
 body{
margin:0px auto;
width:80%;
height:80%;
}


#map_size{
width:800px;
height:800px;
background:#0099FF;
border-style: solid;
border-color: black;
}

#desk_box{ 
width: 20px;
height: 30px;
border:5px solid black; 
margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: There is no position:center.

Comment: where exactly? I updated my code just now

Comment: #map_size has position:center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% clear on what you want, but is this what you are looking for?:

```
<?php

//get number of rows for X,Y coords in the table
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($coord_result)){    
//naming X,Y values
$desk[] = array('x' => $row['x_coord'], 
                                            'y' => $row['y_coord']);

    foreach($coord_result as $row){
    echo"<div id='desk_box' style='top:".$desk[0]."; left:".$desk[1]."';">box number #number written here</div>";
        }
    //draw a box with a DIV at its X,Y coord     
        } //end while coord_result loop

?>
```

And the CSS to go with it:

```
#map_size{
width:800px;
height:800px;
background:#0099FF;
border-style: solid;
border-color: black;
position: relative;
}


#desk_box{ 
width: 20px;
height: 30px;
border:5px solid black; 
margin: 10px;
position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: basically im doing a cartesian map, and want to place each box on their appropriate position.. plus I just tested your code and the syntax is wrong.. I had to change the double quotes for single quotes.. and well the loop doesnt stop it keeps on going when theres only 5 rows in my table.

Comment: i had to place  the for loop outside the while loop. I get 5 boxes which is good, now i want to place them at their appropriate position

Comment: I added the CSS necessary and fixed the quotes. Hopefully that will work.

Comment: thanks ! I used position:relative and it worked. I kept how my php code as it is. would you know how I can leave spaces between those boxes so they wont gap between each other? @coopersita

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean "gap between each other"? The absolute position will overlap them, if they are placed close to each other.

Comment: sorry yes I meant I don't want them to overlap

Comment: It all depends on the coordinates you give. if you want them separated, then place them further apart.

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

```
<div id="map_size" align="center">
<?php
//get number of rows for X,Y coords in the table
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($coord_result)){    
    //naming X,Y values
    $desk[] = array('x' => $row['x_coord'],'y' => $row['y_coord']);
    foreach($coord_result as $row){
      echo '<div style="postion:absolute;left:'. $row['x_coord'] . 'px; top:'. $row['y_coord']'.;" id=desk_box>box number #number written here</div>';
    }
    //draw a box with a DIV at its X,Y coord     
  } //end while coord_result loop

?>

</div>
```

Comment: I had to place the foreach loop outside the while for it to work. Still instead of being in different locations their all under each other

Comment: where can we see it or can you paste some generated html?

Comment: I got it working its good. Now I just want to use css to I leave space between these boxes Divs each time they are drawn on screen.